# which process to use for encoding and editing videos in android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

i want to build a video editor like this app [Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nexstreaming.app.kinemasterfree)

my problem is that should i use ffmpeg or any other similar library to encode the videos to edit and then to decode them
or should i use completely different approach to edit the videos.
any help will be appreciated

Comment: i solved this problem

Comment: now i am using ffmpeg and i am able to use these features in my app

Comment: reverse the video and apply different effects and trim or crop the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make a list of your proposed features then check if FFmpeg can do them? That will answer your own question.

You can use FFmpeg to decode various formats to raw data like pixels (for image) and PCM (for audio) then use the audio programming skills or pixel manipulation skills you already have to modify the data. If you have no skills then you're limited to making a user-interface for FFmpeg, aren't you?

For example : If a user moves the slider to adjust image (video frame) brightness is your code using a `for` loop to adjust each pixel values or maybe you're using a `colorMatrix`? How will you show live preview since FFmpeg must first encode the entire video with new brightness. This information is missing from your question.

Then use FFmpeg again to re-encode to output format (some formats like MPEG require a paid license to encode data in its format by any "paid-for" software so check your rights as Android developer, maybe Google covered that step for you).

Comment: thank you for your time i also have one more problem that how can i compile the current version of ffmpeg for android in windows

Comment: can you suggest me some pixel manipulation tutorials or study materials